# How to check one CheckBox and uncheck other CheckBox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to check one CheckBox and uncheck other CheckBox in Xamarin.Forms.

This is my XAML:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding checkboxcontrol1command}"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label Text="ABS control module" FontSize="13" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" Margin="20,0,0,0"/> 
    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource checkboxpopup}" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck}" />
</StackLayout>
```

And int the ViewModel:

```
private async Task CheckBoxControl()
{
    if(AddRemoveContentResource.Current.IsCheck==true)
    {
        AddRemoveContentResource.Current.IsCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        AddRemoveContentResource.Current.IsCheck = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using radio button in that case? Please refer this to have an idea about radio button: https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit

Comment: how to use Radio Button..i am writing <RadionButton> in xaml bu there is no definition for it.

Comment: Have you referred the document, they have explained step by step process: https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit/wiki/Getting-Started You need to install plugin to use that.

Comment: thanks #MShah. it will be helpful for me

Comment: Writing it as an answer, accept it so that, it might get helped any one else, Thanks.

Comment: @shanmuhammad Hi , If answer be helpful , remember to mark it when you have time .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Radio button` in such cases, where you only want to check one among all items.
You can refer this to implement radio button in Xamarin: https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit

They have provided step by step guide for the same: https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit/wiki/Getting-Started

**Example:**

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample.InputKit"
            xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"
            x:Class="Sample.InputKit.MainPage">

        <StackLayout Spacing="12" Padding="30,0">

            <input:RadioButtonGroupView>
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 1" />
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 2" />
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 3" />
                <input:RadioButton Text="Option 4" />
            </input:RadioButtonGroupView>

        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```